# Need to remove a <br> with JS/CSS

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

Here is the code I am having an issue with

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //<![CDATA[

        $('#blocked_file_extensions').popover({
      'placement': 'bottom',
      "title": "Blocked Extensions",
      "content": "These filetypes will be blocked:`<br>` exe, vbs, pif, scr, bat, cmd, com, cpl, mp3, avi"
    });

    //]]>
    </script>
```

Directly after this sentence "These filetypes will be blocked:" You will notice a `<br>` tag. I am trying to remove the`<br>` with JS but I can't seem to target it. I do not have access to this portion of the code and I can only use JS or CSS to change/remove items.

I have tried a few remove and replace functions with no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: What plugin provides the `.popover()` jQuery extension? The markup generated by this plugin is necessary to target the `<br>`.

Comment: After the content is rendered, use your browser's inspector to see where in the DOM it's located.  That should help you target the element.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a look at trying to overwrite the option in your js code. Haven't used popover before, but [according to the docs you can do something like this](http://daveyijzermans.nl/jquery/popover/demo.html#methods_setOption):

```
$("#blocked_file_extensions").popover(
    'setOption'
    , 'content'
    , "These filetypes will be blocked: exe, vbs, pif, scr, bat, cmd, com, cpl, mp3, avi"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using the [twitter bootstrap `.popover`](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers)

You could destroy the popover and redefine it with the options you want..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

$('#blocked_file_extensions').popover('destroy');
$('#blocked_file_extensions').popover({
      'placement': 'bottom',
      "title": "Blocked Extensions",
      "content": "whatever content you want ..."
    });

//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you are going to fix this...

Create a modified script out of the original script and remove the original.

**Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fixScript() {
        // Get all the scripts in the page
        var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName( 'script' );

        for(var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
            // Find the script we need
            if(scripts[i].childNodes[0] != undefined) {
                if(scripts[i].childNodes[0].textContent.indexOf("<br>") !== -1) {
                    // Get the code from the script
                    newData = scripts[i].childNodes[0].textContent.replace("<br>", "");

                    // Remove the old script
                    scripts[i].parentNode.removeChild(scripts[i]);

                    // Create a new script with fixed data
                    var s1 = document.createElement("script");
                    s1.type = "text/javascript"; 
                    s1.textContent = newData;
                    var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
                    s.parentNode.insertBefore(s1, s);

                    // Stop
                    break;
                }
            }
        }   
    }
</script>
```

**Output**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

        $('#blocked_file_extensions').popover({
      'placement': 'bottom',
      "title": "Blocked Extensions",
      "content": "These filetypes will be blocked:`` exe, vbs, pif, scr, bat, cmd, com, cpl, mp3, avi"
    });

    //]]>
</script>
```